# Events on domain entities?

Tags: c#, events, dns

I just want to discuss pros and cons with my idea.

I've taken over a ASP.NET solution where most of the logic is placed in UserControls and there code behind. I'm trying to refactor this as new features is introduced and now I'm facing a new problem.

At the moment mail alerts are sent in the code behind but I'm thinking of a way to move this in to separate classes. This is what I'm thinking:

Add static events to the domain classes, ie. BookingAccepted, BookingRejected and so on. And then hook into these events with a class that takes care of the e-mail sending.

This means adding events to the domain entities. Is this a good or bad idea? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain events mechanism is a good idea. But implementation can be different, static very often  not the best way. I like Udi Dahan's idea, look to this [blog post](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/)

Comment: Great post! I did some testing with a static delegate on the accual entity but it feels dirty and hard to unit test. What do you think regarding the fact that the events introduces complexity to the code?

Comment: I think it gets more benefits from easier component integration. Then you can use this mechanism on a different level of your application: do some event logging, send ui notifications, collect some statistic. You put this logic to appropriate levels and benefit from this much more valuable then additional few lines in your domain model. And when you app becomes bigger it becomes more helpful.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but... There is exactly zero functional difference between using a static event and using an example like Mr. Dahan's. Even the 'unit test' example he showed would be exactly the same by subscribing to the static event instead of using a static class. The only difference, then, is that he is declaring two unneeded interfaces and an unneeded static class.

Answer (score 1):

Sending email notification looks like infrastructure thing. Thus, I'd moved this logic to application/domain services (same place, where you are talking to repositories, do logging, etc). You don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` by your domain objects for logging and persisting. Same with sending emails.

Comment: So what you are saying is that this should be din the a service method and not using events? why is that "better"?